# Why do conforming implementations behave differently w.r.t. incomplete array types with internal linkage?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c11, standards-compliance, incomplete-type

Sample code (t0.c):

```
static int arr[ ];

int main( void )
{
        return arr[ 0 ];
}

static int arr[ ] = { 0 };
```

Invocations:

```
$ gcc t0.c -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra
<nothing>

$ clang t0.c -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra
<nothing>

$ cl t0.c /std:c11 /Za
t0.c(1): error C2133: 'arr': unknown size

$ gcc t0.c -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
t0.c:1:12: error: array size missing in ‘arr’

$ clang t0.c -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
<nothing>
```

C11, 6.2.5 Types, 22:

> An array type of unknown size is an incomplete type. It is completed, for an identifier of that type, by specifying the size in a later declaration (with internal or external linkage).

C11, 6.9.2 External object definitions, 3:

> If the declaration of an identifier for an object is a tentative definition and has internal linkage, the declared type shall not be an incomplete type.

C11, J.2 Undefined behavior, 1:

> An identifier for an object with internal linkage and an incomplete type is declared with a tentative definition (6.9.2).

Question: Why do conforming implementations show different behavior? Which one behaves correctly?

UPD1. Created https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=51319.

Comment: At first glance I'd say this is a plain old bug in clang. They forgot the special case for tentative definitions with internal linkage. Out of curiosity, does clang's behavior change if you add `-fno-common` to the command line?

Comment: @zwol doesn't seem like it does: https://godbolt.org/z/3bTqs64PW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the quoted passages, particularly 6.9.2p3 and the non-normative J.2p1, it seems clear that the code violates these clauses and therefore may not appear in a *strictly conforming program* defined in section 4p5 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> A *strictly  conforming  program* shall  use  only  those  features
> of  the  language  and  library specified  in  this  International
> Standard. It  shall  not  produce  output  dependent  on  any
> unspecified,  undefined,  or  implementation-defined  behavior,  and
> shall  not  exceed  any minimum implementation limit

Implementations are however free to define extensions that would not be allowed in a strictly conforming program.  A program using such extensions is a *conforming program* as defined in section 4p6:

> The two forms of *conforming implementation* are hosted and
> freestanding.  A *conforming hosted  implementation* shall  accept
> any  strictly  conforming  program.  [ ... *details of freestanding omitted* ... ]  A  conforming
> implementation  may  have  extensions  (including additional  library
> functions),  provided  they  do  not  alter  the  behavior  of  any
> strictly conforming program

Based on the compiler output, it appears that MSVC does not support such an extension but gcc and clang do.

Additionally, gcc correctly disables this feature when the `-pedantic` flag is passed, forcing strict compliance.  That clang does not generate a diagnostic with `-pedantic` appears to be a bug.

Comment: Thanks. If 6.9.2p3 prohibits "internal linkage" case, then why 6.2.5p22 does mention "internal linkage" in parentheses?

Comment: At the beginning the 6.2.5p22 talks about arrays. Hence, the "it" == "array" and "internal linkage" in parentheses is related to arrays. Or do I miss something?

Comment: I guess that extension cannot cancel the existing standard requirements. I guess that extension is a feature, which is 1) on top of the existing features, 2) does not break the existing features. In our case we see that "no-diagnostics" extension supported by compiler implementations (presented above) cancels the standard requirement 6.9.2p3. Hence, such compiler implementations are non-conforming. How can you comment on that?

Comment: @pmor The purpose of an extension is to allow features that would not otherwise be allowed by the standard, and this is one of those cases. The fact that clang does not generate a warning in pedantic mode I would consider a bug, but gcc is still conforming.